# How are Symfony services private by default?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

From the [official release](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default), Symfony services are private by default. But when I run `debug` command on my Symfony-4.4 container:

`bin/console debug:container`

It still lists a lot of Symfony framework built-in services as `public`.

Does this `private/public` feature not apply to command line operations?

Comment: The command description for `debug:container` seems to be misleading. Not all the services listed are public. Check with many of them and you'll see that they are actually `public: no`.

Answer (score 0):

The debug:container command for example hides the private services by default, so it's no longer useful to list the services available in your application. That's why in Symfony 4.1 we've changed the debug:container command to show the private services by default and we've also deprecated the --show-private option.
See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-hidden-services

Comment: Yes I got that from the documentation, but my question is: How come so many services are still listed as ```public``` via the command ```debug:container```, after Symfony official document says all services are ```private``` by default?